# How To pass whole table rows and columns as single parameter in ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, foreach, playframework

I would like to send all the selected row values of a table in a single parameter in ajax. Please find below code in which I am sending as one by one using for each statement. If table has 7000 rows. It will not give optimum performance.

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body>                        
<tr>
<th ><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />SELECT</th>
<th>DEPARTMENT</th><th>BOXNO</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>STATUS</th></tr><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<button  id="save">Finish</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectall').click(function(event) {
          $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
$("#save").click(function() {
    console.log("recorded");
      //get all the checked checboxex
      $('#tab input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        //for each checked checkbox, iterate through its parent's siblings
        var array = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
          return $(this).text().trim();
        }).get();
        //to print the value of array
        console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
         $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.saveboxes()',
             data : {
                 dept: array[0],
                 boxnumber:array[1],
                 qty:array[2],
                 orgname:'IN1005',
                 packeddate:array[3]
             },
             success : function(data) {
                 $("#alreadyscan").slideUp();
                $('#completescan').slideDown();

                jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
                //location.reload();

           },
             error : function() {
                 $('#completescan').slideUp();
                 $("#alreadyscan").slideDown();
                 //alert("Error IN UP")
             }

             });
      })
});

</script>
```

If possible please give me how to receive the same in Java end aswell

Answer (score 0):

`table` is NOT supposed to send any data! Build a proper form with proper form fields, so you can just serialize it i.e. to JSON and send via AJAX.

Comment: I am not sending table. I am reading values from rows of a table and sending as one by one. It would be great if you provide me way to do it as whole. Thanks a lot